# Retrieving a parcelable ArrayList from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, arraylist, parcelable

I'm having issues retrieving an ArrayList from one activity to other. My Video class implements Parcelable.

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Bundle b = mVideos.get(numero).getAsBundle();
        Bundle a = new Bundle();
        // putting the parcelable mVideos, which is an array, into the bundle.
        a.putParcelableArrayList("videos", mVideos);
        final Intent i = new Intent("com.video.tv.description");
        i.putExtra("com.video.tv.description", b);
        i.putExtra("com.video.tv.Videos", a); // I added it to intent
        dAct.startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

How can i retrieve the whole array on the second activity?

```
Bundle a = i.getBundleExtra("com.video.tv.Videos")??
```

I'm trying to get the whole array as it was before on my initial activity.

Comment: `putParcelableArrayList` goes with ... `getParcelableArrayList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dYour code is very strange, it looks like you have a lot of unecessary Bundles and things floating around Try the following when you are constructing your bundle:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // What is the purpose of this line?
        Bundle b = mVideos.get(numero).getAsBundle();
        Bundle a = new Bundle();
        a.putParcelableArrayList("videos", mVideos);
        // Replace YourNewActivity with the name of the Activity you want to start.
        Intent i = new Intent(dAct, YourNewActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("description", b);
        i.putExtra("videos", a); // I added it to intent
        dAct.startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Then, in your receiving activity, do the following to get the list:

```
Bundle i = getIntent().getExtras();
Bundle a = i.getBundleExtra("com.video.tv.Videos");
ArrayList<Video> videos = a.getParcelableArrayList("videos");
```

Comment: initially I only needed one bundle, but then I realized that i also needed to pass in an arrayList of objects. how would you suggest fixing it?

Comment: Can you clarify for me where you are launching the intent? Are you in an activity?

Comment: Why are you adding the listener here? Why not add an OnClickListener to your adapter when you use it?

Comment: because i was trying to implement a horizontalListView, and my way around it was to add HorizontalScrollView and then call 
HorizontalGalleryAdapter adapter = new HorizontalGalleryAdapter(this,mVideos);
  for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
     View item = adapter.getView(i, null, null);
     LL.addView(item);
  }

  horizontalScroll.addView(LL);

Comment: that was really confusing. but essentially i'm using an adapter and then doing a View item = adapter.getView(i,null,null) inside a for loop. this way I populate the horizontalScrollView pragramatically and it sort of simulates a ListView. The problem with doing that is that I can't add adapterView to HorizontalScrollView, so I had to put a setOnCLickListener inside my getView

Comment: Ok, as long as that works. I take it you're storing an instance of your activity in the adapter or something like that?

Comment: yes indeed. I have an instance of the activity on the adapter

Comment: Ok. Ahh, so I take it that is `dAct`?

Comment: And can you clarify what this is supposed to do? `Bundle b = mVideos.get(numero).getAsBundle();`

Comment: Yes you're correct. mVideos.get(numero) gets the correct video from the array. getAsBundle() is a Bundle function that i wrote for my video class. it just puts the properties of the video on a bundle.  b.putString("title", mTitle) and so on